# UrlConnection making 2 GET requests

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

My HttpUrlConnection is making 2 requests where as i am just sending it once in my code.

Here is my code below:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                    try
                    {


                        URL myUrl = new URL("http://" + url);
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");
                        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("my-header", header);
                        int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                        if(code != -1)
                        {
                            wv.loadUrl(myUrl.toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + url);
                            et_URL.setText(wv.getUrl());

                }
```

When i see logs from server its show me 2 GET requests.
Any body any idea??

Comment: Can u add more code? With proper blocks ending

Comment: @jazz11.. you mean sever logs ?

Comment: No, the client code. Your code till here looks fine. We need to see rest of the code.

Comment: This is all the code related to opening a URL in a webView.. i just want to make an HTTP GET call to the server with some headers and load it in the WebView that i have.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-http-client-get-post-download-upload-multipart-request.html

Hi, its a very good example of how to use HTTP Requests in Android, I prefer to use Volley library its very easy to implement :)

```
    private String RegisterUser(String urlString) {

        ok = true;
        String result = null;

        try {

            Log.d(TAG, "UrlString:" + urlString);

            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

            HttpURLConnection con = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d(TAG, "open connection");

            con.setReadTimeout(1000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);

            // start the query
            con.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected");

            if (Thread.interrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException();

            InputStream response = con.getInputStream();

            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

            // Scanner sc = new Scanner(con.getInputStream());

            result = "OK";

            Log.d(TAG, "Result:" + result);

            // sc.close();
            con.disconnect();

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // showInfoDialog("Error while accesing the web service");
            Log.d(TAG, e + "");
            return "Error";
        }

    }
```

Comment: No but do you have any idea about am i doing something wrong while making a request in the above code?

Comment: Code above seems good, but you don't show us the rest of the code, thats why I linked an example how it's done usually.

Comment: This is all the code related to opening a URL in a webView.. i just want to make an HTTP GET call to the server with some headers and load it in the WebView that i have.

Comment: I pasted one of my GET requests it works perfectly for me. If you get 2 requests again with my version then I can only think of that first is from the urlconnection and the second is from loading the url in the webview.

Comment: But how to load the url in the WebView?..... I need to set headers in GET method and then load the URL in my webView.... I am new to android that why i do no  know much things..

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple version of how to load an url in a webview but you can do even css with assets google it up if you are interested in that version:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/mainWebView">
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first GET request is initiated by this line:

```
int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

the second GET request occurs when the WebView loads the URL:

```
wv.loadUrl(myUrl.toString());
```